# Unable to give the file path to the style dictionary

Tags: .net, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

I am working on a .net project where I have to convert features into graphics to show them with stored symbols.

I have a separate style file as .stylx and geodatabase file as .goedatabase.zip which I want to utilize to show my symbole of the style file.

I successfully execute the below code and show may map. But I am unable to access my style library and geodatabase which is stored on my drive.

Below are the specs of my files

- **mil2525d.stylx** - A stylx file for use with ArcGIS Runtime 100.0 -
  100.4 to build custom applications that incorporate the MIL-STD-2525D symbol dictionary.
- **militaryoverlay.geodatabase.zip** - This is a mobile geodatabase
  created from the Military Overlay template for use in ArcGIS Runtime
  samples

Any help

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using ArcGISRuntime.Samples.Managers;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping;
using Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology;

namespace ArcGISRuntime.WPF.Samples.FeatureLayerDictionaryRenderer
{
    [ArcGISRuntime.Samples.Shared.Attributes.Sample(
        name: "Dictionary renderer with feature layer",
        category: "Layers",
        description: "Convert features into graphics to show them with mil2525d symbols.",
        instructions: "Pan and zoom around the map. Observe the displayed military symbology on the map.",
        tags: new[] { "military", "symbol" })]
    [ArcGISRuntime.Samples.Shared.Attributes.OfflineData("c78b149a1d52414682c86a5feeb13d30", "e0d41b4b409a49a5a7ba11939d8535dc")]
    public partial class FeatureLayerDictionaryRenderer
    {
        public FeatureLayerDictionaryRenderer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Setup the control references and execute initialization
            Initialize();
        }

        private async void Initialize()
        {
            // Create new Map with basemap
            Map myMap = new Map(BasemapStyle.ArcGISTopographic);

            // Provide Map to the MapView
            MyMapView.Map = myMap;

            // Get the path to the geodatabase
            string geodbFilePath = GetGeodatabasePath();

            // Load the geodatabase from local storage
            Geodatabase baseGeodatabase = await Geodatabase.OpenAsync(geodbFilePath);

            // Get the path to the symbol dictionary
            string symbolFilepath = GetStyleDictionaryPath();

            try
            {
                // Load the symbol dictionary from local storage
                DictionarySymbolStyle symbolStyle = await DictionarySymbolStyle.CreateFromFileAsync(symbolFilepath);

                // Add geodatabase features to the map, using the defined symbology
                foreach (FeatureTable table in baseGeodatabase.GeodatabaseFeatureTables)
                {
                    // Load the table
                    await table.LoadAsync();

                    // Create the feature layer from the table
                    FeatureLayer myLayer = new FeatureLayer(table);

                    // Load the layer
                    await myLayer.LoadAsync();

                    // Create a Dictionary Renderer using the DictionarySymbolStyle
                    DictionaryRenderer dictRenderer = new DictionaryRenderer(symbolStyle);

                    // Apply the dictionary renderer to the layer
                    myLayer.Renderer = dictRenderer;

                    // Add the layer to the map
                    myMap.OperationalLayers.Add(myLayer);
                }

                // Create geometry for the center of the map
                MapPoint centerGeometry = new MapPoint(-13549402.587055, 4397264.96879385, SpatialReference.Create(3857));

                // Set the map's viewpoint to highlight the desired content
                MyMapView.SetViewpoint(new Viewpoint(centerGeometry, 201555));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use public sample with your own data, you could either simple replace data in code as follows:

```
// Get the path to the geodatabase
string geodbFilePath = "c:/path_to_gdb/mygdb.geodatabase";

// Load the geodatabase from local storage
Geodatabase baseGeodatabase = await Geodatabase.OpenAsync(geodbFilePath);

// Get the path to the symbol dictionary
string symbolFilepath = "c:/path_to_style/mystylx.stylx";
```

or modify `GetGeodatabasePath` and `GetStyleDictionaryPath` methods to point to your data locations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).